# Wordpress widget php file is not translatable with PO files

Tags: php, po

Can anyone help me why these strings in the php are not translatable?
How am I supposed to change the code, so that the "Jhon" & "Doe" placeholders can be translatable using PO edit?

```
        'first_name_input'    => [
            'type'        => 'text',
            'name'        => 'first_name',
            'id'          => 'first_name' . esc_attr( $id ),
            'placeholder' => ($settings['first_name_placeholder']) ? $settings['first_name_placeholder'] : 'Jhon',
            'class'       => [
                'first_name',
                'bdt-input',
                'bdt-form-' . $settings['input_size'],
            ],
        ],
        'last_name_input'     => [
            'type'        => 'text',
            'name'        => 'last_name',
            'id'          => 'last_name' . esc_attr( $id ),
            'placeholder' => ($settings['last_name_placeholder']) ? $settings['last_name_placeholder'] : 'Doe',
            'class'       => [
                'last_name',
                'bdt-input',
                'bdt-form-' . $settings['input_size'],
            ],
        ],
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is the similar of `<input type='text'.... placeholder='anything here'>`

So you cant really translate it directly because you will be in fact changing programming parameters, but answering your question, i think it will do the trick:

`'placeholder' => ($settings['first_name_placeholder']) ? $settings['first_name_placeholder'] : 'Your Name'`

`'placeholder' => ($settings['last_name_placeholder']) ? $settings['last_name_placeholder'] : 'Your Last Name'`

Change "Your Name" and "Your Last Name" to whatever you want and it'llbe ok :)